# How do i delete a hole row in php?

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have to buttons one to display the info of each order and one to delete the order after been dispatch. How can i make the delete button work. Because the "view-order works but the delete one doesn't. I need to delete each row individually with the button.

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconnection.php';

$sql = "SELECT * from Orders";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result -> num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr><td>". $row["name"] ."</td><td>". $row["student_id"] ."</td><td>". $row["ordr_num"]
        ."</td><td><button class='btn btn-small' id='{$row["ordr_num"]}'>View Order</button></td>
         <td><button class='btn btn-small'}'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "0 result";
}
```

i need to be able to delete each row individually but i really don't know how. I tried running a delete scrip before my if but it didn't work.

Comment: Please make sure to sanitize your data to prevent cross site scripting.

Comment: We can't really tell you how to implement the "Delete" button with so little information. The `}'` in `<button class='btn btn-small'}'>Delete</button>` doesn't look like it belongs there, though. You probably wanted to give the button an id, there.

Comment: sorry guys for my mistakes, learning on how to post here.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you're learning the PHP because the way that you're developing it's a bad practice. So, I will give you a solution to your request.

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconnection.php';

if(isset($_GET['idDelete'])){
  $resultDelete = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM Orders WHERE ordr_num = " . $_GET['idDelete']);
  if($resultDelete->affected_rows > 0){
    echo "Order # " . $_GET['idDelete'] . " has been deleted";
  }else{
    echo "Order # " . $_GET['idDelete'] . " couldn't be deleted.";
  }
}


$sql = "SELECT * from Orders";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result -> num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>
                <td>". $row["name"] ."</td>
                <td>". $row["student_id"] ."</td>
                <td>". $row["ordr_num"]."</td>
                <td><button class='btn btn-small' id='" . $row["ordr_num"] ."'>View Order</button></td>
                <td><a href='?idDelete=".$row["ordr_num"]."' class='btn btn-small'>Delete</a></td>
             </tr>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "0 result";
}

?>
```

Comment: yes, sorry if i did it wrong im here stuck trying to learn php for web dev.

Comment: i got this error using your code:

Notice: Trying to get property 'affected_rows' of non-object in /Users/raphaelsmac/Sites/Appex-master/includes/order-data.php on line 7
Order # 204590 couldn't be deleted.

Comment: I forgot that you're not using Oriented Object Connection.Please Change ** $resultDelete->affected_rows > 0 ** TO ** mysqli_affected_rows($resultDelete) > 0. The error is the message but the row must disappear..